# how to define the dual of a primal assignment-like program with Hadamard product as a cost function?

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems, integer-programming

I need to define the dual of the assignment-like problem where the cost function is defined as the Hadamard product of two matrices $C=[c_{ij}]$ and $X=[x_{ij}]$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\text{minimize $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_{ij}$}& \\
\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} &= 1 &&\forall i \\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}r_{i} &\le b_j &&\forall j \\
x_{i,j} &\in \left\{0,1\right\} &&\forall i,j
\end{align}

I tried to construct the dual problem from this primal formulation but I am not sure how to define it. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Very peculiar to have open set constraints in an LP.

Comment: @RobPratt, you are right. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dual of the linear programming relaxation of the primal, I suggest omitting the upper bound on $x_{i,j}$ because it complicates the dual and is already implied by nonnegativity and the first constraint.  Introduce a (free) dual variable $\alpha_i$ for the first constraint and a nonpositive dual variable $\beta_j$ for the second constraint.  The primal is minimization, so the dual is maximization.  The primal objective coefficients become the dual RHS, and vice versa.  The dual constraint matrix is the transpose of the primal constraint matrix.

Comment: I need to use later the ADMM technique but not sure if the by omitting the upper bound on $x_{i,j}$ I would get a feasible solution knowing that I need to relax the variable to make it convex. Correct me if I am wrong @RobPratt.

Comment: As far as I understand, ADMM uses two sets of variables.  Are you applying ADMM to the primal problem, which has only one set of variables?

Comment: In the primal problem, the second term that I omitted here is in the form of \begin{align}
\text{$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n x_{ij}$}\sum\limits_{k=1,k!=j}^n\sum\limits_{l=1, l!=i}^n x_{lk} \times b(i,k)& \\
\end{align}